# SwiftUI NavigationView caret position

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

Looking to find a way to have the NavigationView caret align to the top right of the row vs. center.  Hoping to find a way to have the caret in line with the title of my article.

[image]

```
List {
    ForEach(searching ? faqTableSearch : faqTable) { section in
        Section(header: Text(section.section)) {
            ForEach(section.faq) { row in
                NavigationLink(destination: FaqView(title: row.title, summary: row.summary, content: row.body)) {
                    VStack {
                        Text(row.title)
                            .font(.custom("Helvetica", size: 16))
                            .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGray))
                            .offset(x: -16)
                        Spacer()
                        Text(row.summary)
                            .font(.custom("Helvetica", size: 12))
                            .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGray))
                            .offset(x: 16)
                    }
                } // end nav
            } // end item
        } // end section
        .font(.custom("Helvetica", size: 17))
    } // end loop
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you can move the standard chevron created by `NavigationLink` in a `NavigationView`, but you can hide the default `NavigationLink` and recreate it with the (very slightly different SF Symbols `chevron.right` or `chevron.forward`):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var items = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                    ZStack {
                        NavigationLink(destination: Text("Detail")) { EmptyView() }.hidden()
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            HStack {
                                Text(item)
                                    .font(.custom("Helvetica", size: 16))
                                    .offset(x: -16)
                                Spacer()
                                Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                            }.foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGray))
                            
                            Spacer()
                            Text(item)
                                .font(.custom("Helvetica", size: 12))
                                .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGray))
                                .offset(x: 16)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This got me 99% of the way there but it was still showing the old nav caret at the same time so adding the .frame and .hidden did the trick:                                          NavigationLink(destination: FaqView(title: row.title, summary: row.summary, content: row.body)) { EmptyView() }
                                            .frame(width: 0, height: 0)
                                            .hidden()

Answer (score 0):

`Image(systemName: "chevron.right").font(.system(size: 14)).opacity(0.3)`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrpDt.png)

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            Section(header: GroupHeader(title: "Example")) {
               NavigationLink(
                    destination: UnderlineTextField_Example(),
                    label: {
                        Text("TextField")
                    }
                )
                
                HStack {
                    Button("Navigation") {
                        isPresented.toggle()
                    }
                    .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresented) {
                        TabNavigation()
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                        .font(.system(size: 14))
                        .opacity(0.3)
                }
        }
}
```